# File on change is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a form in which the user can submit a post. This post has required user inputs like title, subject and text body and not required user inputs like a link and a browse file to submit a picture. I am using jQuery and Ajax to submit form. The problem is that the `.on('change', function(){});` is not working inside the `.click()` function. I am not able to identify the problem nevertheless I tested each jQuery function alone and they worked fine alone, but when nested one inside the other it is not working.

Here are the jQuery codes:

```
$(document.body).delegate("#discussion_submit_button", "click", function(){ 
    var title = $("#discussion_title").val();
    var link = $("#discussion_link").val();
    var subjects = $("#discussion_subjects").val();
    var discussion = $("#discussion_input_textarea").val();
    var fileSelected = 0;

    if (title == '' || subjects == '' || discussion == '') { 
        $(".discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields").fadeIn("Slow");
        // error message, we select span tag with ID error_message and we change its content to this text
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields').fadeOut("Slow");
        }, 2000); 
    } else {
        $(document.body).delegate("#discussion_file_upload", "change", function(){ 
        //$('#discussion_file_upload').on('change', function(){
            fileSelected = 1;

        });
        alert(fileSelected); // this is giving a result of 0
    }
});
```

And here is the form HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="discussion_form" id="discussion_form">
    <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Title</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
    <div class="discussion_input_div"><input type="text" name="discussion_title" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_title"/></div>
    <div class="discussion_label_div">Link (optional)</div>
    <div class="discussion_input_div"><input type="text" name="discussion_link" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_link"/></div>
    <div class="discussion_label_div">Image (optional)</div>
    <div class="discussion_input_div"><label for="discussion_file_upload"><span class="imageUploadIcon"></span><span id="imageUploadWord">SELECT FILE TO UPLOAD</span></label><input type="file" name="discussion_image" class="discussion_file_input" id="discussion_file_upload"/></div>
    <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Subject</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
    <div class="discussion_input_div">
        <select name="discussions_subjects" id="discussion_subjects">
            <option disabled selected>Select a subject</option> <!-- disabled prevent the user from selecting this option and selected makes it selected at the start -->
            <?php
                $subjects = array('Advice', 'Animals', 'Art', 'DIY', 'Engineering', 'Entertainment', 'Fashion', 'Food', 'Funny', 'Gaming', 'General', 'Health', 
                'Memes', 'Movies', 'Music', 'News', 'Outdoors', 'Philosophy', 'Photography', 'Politics', 'Relationships', 'Religion', 'Science', 'Sports', 'Tourism', 'TV', 
                'Video Games', 'Writing');
                foreach ($subjects as $subject){
                ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $subject;?>">
                <?php echo $subject; ?>
            </option>
            <?php

                }
            ?>                  
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Discussion</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="discussion_textarea" class="discussion_input_textarea" placeholder="Open your discussion..." id="discussion_input_textarea"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="discussion_submit_button" value="Assert" class="share_button" id="discussion_submit_button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Of course it's going to alert 0. The `change` eventListener waits until something changed to run the code in the function. The alert fires way before that

Comment: `delegate()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead. Placing `on('change')` inside `on('click')` makes no sense. Move it outside. The alert is executed immediately before the event is fired, so move it inside the `on('change')`.

Comment: i change the file then i click on submit button so it is giving an alert of 0, but it should change because the value becomes 1

Comment: No it shouldn't. When you change the file, there is no event attached. You only attach it after the click. So the code inside the event is not executed. Follow my comment above.

Comment: @RacilHilan i do not want to alert actually but it is for debugging, so you suggest i put the on change outside and if it happens it then changes the fileSelected variable ? and if not selected the form will submit the required inputs ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You also need to move the `fileSelected` outside with the event. However, you don't really need it as you can easily check if there is file or not.

Comment: ok i did what you suggested and it worked :) but i did not understand how i do not need the `fileSelected` variable and how to check if there is file or not ?

Comment: When you select a file (or multiple files), the `files` property contains a list of the selected files. So you can simply use `files.length` to know how many files are selected. If no files selected, it will be zero. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`delegate()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead. Placing `on("change")` inside `on("click")` makes no sense. Move it outside:

```
var fileSelected = 0;
$('#discussion_file_upload').on("change", function(){
    fileSelected = 1;
});

$("#discussion_submit_button").on("click", function(){ 
    //...your code
    alert(fileSelected);
});
```

However, you don't really need the `fileSelected` variable, you can check the selected files directly using the `files` property. In this case, you don't even need the `on("change")` event altogether:

```
$("#discussion_submit_button").on("click", function(){ 
    //...your code
    alert($('#discussion_file_upload').files.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code will run just how you wrote it:

```
//This code attaches the event handler but does not call it
$(document.body).delegate("#discussion_file_upload", "change", function(){ 
    // The code in this block doesn't fire until a "change" event comes in
    fileSelected = 1;
});
// This alert happens right after the handler is attached, but before it fired.
alert(fileSelected); // therefore it is giving a result of 0
```

And all that happens only after the "`click`" event fires

I think this is what you aim to accomplish:

```js
var fileSelected = 0;

$(document.body).on("click", "#discussion_submit_button", function(){ 
    var title = $("#discussion_title").val();
    var link = $("#discussion_link").val();
    var subjects = $("#discussion_subjects").val();
    var discussion = $("#discussion_input_textarea").val();
    

    if (title == '' || subjects == '' || discussion == '') { 
        $(".discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields").fadeIn("Slow");
        // error message, we select span tag with ID error_message and we change its content to this text
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields').fadeOut("Slow");
        }, 2000); 
    } else {
        console.log("#files:", fileSelected); // this is giving a result of 0
    }
});

$(document.body).on("change", "#discussion_file_upload", function(){ 
    fileSelected = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" class="discussion_form" id="discussion_form">
        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Title</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
        <div class="discussion_input_div"><input type="text" name="discussion_title" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_title"/></div>
        <div class="discussion_label_div">Link (optional)</div>
        <div class="discussion_input_div"><input type="text" name="discussion_link" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_link"/></div>
        <div class="discussion_label_div">Image (optional)</div>
        <div class="discussion_input_div"><label for="discussion_file_upload"><span class="imageUploadIcon"></span><span id="imageUploadWord">SELECT FILE TO UPLOAD</span></label><input type="file" name="discussion_image" class="discussion_file_input" id="discussion_file_upload"/></div>
        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Subject</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
        <div class="discussion_input_div">
            <select name="discussions_subjects" id="discussion_subjects">
                <option disabled selected>Select a subject</option> <!-- disabled prevent the user from selecting this option and selected makes it selected at the start -->
                <option value="2">Another option</option>
                <?php
                    $subjects = array('Advice', 'Animals', 'Art', 'DIY', 'Engineering', 'Entertainment', 'Fashion', 'Food', 'Funny', 'Gaming', 'General', 'Health', 
                    'Memes', 'Movies', 'Music', 'News', 'Outdoors', 'Philosophy', 'Photography', 'Politics', 'Relationships', 'Religion', 'Science', 'Sports', 'Tourism', 'TV', 
                    'Video Games', 'Writing');
                    foreach ($subjects as $subject){
                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $subject;?>">
                    <?php echo $subject; ?>
                </option>
                <?php

                    }
                ?>                  
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Discussion</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="discussion_textarea" class="discussion_input_textarea" placeholder="Open your discussion..." id="discussion_input_textarea"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="discussion_submit_button" value="Assert" class="share_button" id="discussion_submit_button"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: yes it is happening like that but the alert is returning a value of 0 instead of 1 :/

Comment: @firashelou right, just like my code says it should.  If you want it to return 1 you need to do like i did in the example snippet.